# How to get rid of spaces between images in CSS?

Tags: html, css

There are spaces rendered between `<div>`s as shown on [this website](http://www.magnixsolutions.com/dev/magicmorgan/indexnew.html). I've set margins, padding, borders to zero, but didn't do the trick. Are there any ways to get rid of those spacings?

Here is the code (the red border is purely for demonstration and will be removed if the problem get fixed):

```html
<style type="text/css">
    body{margin: 0 auto;}
    #content{text-align:center; float:center; white-space:nowrap;}
    .content-left{width:200px; display: inline-block; border:1px solid red; vertical-align:top;}
    .content-center{width:950px; display: inline-block; border:1px solid red; vertical-align:top;}
    .content-right{width:300px; display: inline-block; border:1px solid red; vertical-align:top;}
</style>

<div id="content">
    <div class="content-left"><img src="images/imglft.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="content-center">
     <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="950" height="1000" id="index" align="middle">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="movie" value="index.swf" />
            <param name="menu" value="false" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
            <embed src="index.swf" menu="false" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="950" height="1000" name="index" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
        </object>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right"><img src="images/imgrt.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use `font-size: 0;` on parent `#content` and then return it to your font size on children like `font-size: 12px;` ...

Or: use `word-spacing: -.43em;` on parent and return it to `word-spacing: 0em;` on children ...

I tested that, and seemed it will work.

Answer (score 3):

The `display: inline-block;` is causing that. This way the `<div>`s behave as if they're inline text. If you remove whitespace between `</div>` and `<div>`, then the problem disappears, like as with normal text.

Rather use `float: left;` instead if all you want is to float them left.

Answer (score 2):

As *BalusC* stated: "The display: inline-block; is causing that. The divs behave as if they're inline text."
**This is absolutely correct.**

### Issue

This is caused by the newline char between your `<div>`-elements.
**See sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/yZQNf/1/

### Sample code

#### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="inline">123</div>
    <div class="inline">456</div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- No newline between divs -->
    <div class="inline">123</div><div class="inline">456</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.inline {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But why are you repeating an already given answer? Just upvote and/or leave a comment if you agree with the answer.

Comment: @BalusC I am explaining the issue further and showing a way to fix the issue without using `float`. -- Whitespace having an impact on the layout is bad, but at least it's possible to work with this isuue if you are not able to use float for some reason.

Comment: Oh sorry, your initial answer existed of only a single sentence repeating my answer. You edited the rest in afterwards. Nevermind me :)