# Why is there an unexplainable gap between these inline-block div elements?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have two inline-block `div` elements, that are the same, positioned next to each other. However, there seems to be a mysterious space of 4 pixels between the two divs despite the margin being set to 0. No parent divs are affecting them — What is going on?

CSS

```css
#container
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background:rgb(255,100,0);
    margin:0px;
    width:40%;
    height:100px;
}
```

[image: Div problem]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: What it SHOULD look like]

Comment: There is a much simpler answer, but this is so old I'm making it a comment. Instead of using inline-block to make them side by side, just use `float: left` and center their container. No gap in my tests.

Answer (score 653, accepted):

In this instance, your `div` elements have been changed from `block` level elements to `inline` elements. A typical characteristic of `inline` elements is that they respect the whitespace in the markup. This explains why a *gap* of space is generated between the elements. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Ab5gq/)

There are a few solutions that can be used to solve this.

### Method 1 - Remove the whitespace from the markup

**Example 1** - Comment the whitespace out: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/C3Sjq/5/)

```
<div>text</div><!--
--><div>text</div><!--
--><div>text</div><!--
--><div>text</div><!--
--><div>text</div>
```

**Example 2** - Remove the line breaks: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/C3Sjq/6/)

```
<div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div><div>text</div>
```

**Example 3** - Close part of the tag on the next line [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/C3Sjq/7/)

```
<div>text</div
><div>text</div
><div>text</div
><div>text</div
><div>text</div>
```

**Example 4** - Close the entire tag on the next line: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/C3Sjq/8/)

```
<div>text
</div><div>text
</div><div>text
</div><div>text
</div><div>text
</div>
```

### Method 2 - Reset the `font-size`

Since the whitespace between the `inline` elements is determined by the `font-size`, you could simply reset the `font-size` to `0`, and thus remove the space between the elements.

Just set `font-size: 0` on the parent elements, and then declare a new `font-size` for the children elements. This works, as demonstrated here [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Ab5gq/3/)

```
#parent {
    font-size: 0;
}

#child {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

This method works pretty well, as it doesn't require a change in the markup; however, it doesn't work if the child element's `font-size` is declared using `em` units. I would therefore recommend removing the whitespace from the markup, or alternatively [**floating the elements**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Ab5gq/4/) and thus avoiding the space generated by `inline` elements.

### Method 3 - Set the parent element to `display: flex`

In some cases, you can also set the `display` of the parent element to `flex`. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2omsbxb/)

This effectively removes the spaces between the elements in [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Don't forget to add appropriate vendor prefixes for additional support.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}
.parent > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
}
.parent > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Sides notes:

It is incredibly unreliable to use negative margins to remove the space between `inline` elements. Please don't use negative margins if there are other, more optimal, solutions.

Comment: Ok I guess i could patch it up with negative margins - thanks :) however i dont know what or how to get rid of whitespace - agh il research it

Comment: Ok negative margin seems to be working fine with no bugs - and thanks, whitespace is really that simple!

Comment: Since no one really bothered to explain **why** this happens... inline (and inline-block) elements respect whitespace in the markup, so what you're seeing is essentially the **space character** between "words" in the markup. Which is why setting a negative `word-spacing` can also "fix" this, although negative word-spacing and negative margin are invalid solutions because the spacing depends on your browser and your font-size (as demonstrated by Josh's last example), so it's going to be the first thing that breaks if you make any changes.

Comment: That moment when you spend 20 minutes debugging your CSS, only to discover Chrome is zoomed in to 110% and there was never a gap at all.

Comment: I think setting `font-size:0` to parent element is not a good solution. It makes impossible to use the relative unity `em`, witch is a very good choice for font-size, because you will be unable to reset the font-size at the inner element.

Comment: @jairhumberto I know that. Did you even read my answer? I said *"however, it doesn't work if the child element's `font-size` is declared using `em` units.  I would therefore recommend removing the whitespace from the markup."*.

Comment: Sorry, I read just the first lines, but even using absolute unity I would never choose that as a solution, the rest of what you pointed out was perfect in my opinion.

Comment: I'd say that `display: flex` is the best solution these days.

Comment: `font-size` was the only one that worked for me for the extra vertical space between two `inline-block` elements (which were that way to `text-align: center` them within another `div`). `flex` completely messed up the layout

Comment: Suggested solutions are fine when you have full control over the styles but not when you do not (i.e. plugins, side-loaded or injected features). I've had reliable result using `0.44em` negative margin.

Comment: You my good sir are level 10 web developer.. I've been doing this a very long time and it didn't even dawn on me to use a comment to remove white spaces. Hats off to you!

Comment: honestly, this makes no sense why this occurs, but this answer is 100% true

Answer (score 38):

Using `inline-block` allows for white-space in your HTML, This usually equates to .25em (or 4px).

You can either comment out the white-space or, a more commons solution, is to set the parent's `font-size` to 0 and the reset it back to the required size on the inline-block elements.

Comment: This is a cool solution that I never thought of, but unfortunately breaks the normal CSS inheritance of font-sizes :/

Comment: @colllin Yes, it does...but you just have to be aware of it. Inline-block and float both have their 'gotchas'...how you resolve them is a matter of choice. The font solution is one option but not the only one.

Comment: sure but reducing the things I "have to be aware of it" is always a good thing, and so is protecting yourself from accidentally breaking something in 6 months.

Comment: @Pauli_D You could also put comments between you elements as they remove the whitespace not only in the document but also on the site. It's a bit ugly and a pain in the butt when you have ton's of elements.

Comment: Thank you, I'm well aware of the various methods of dealing with `inline-block`...this is just one **from two years ago**

Answer (score 18):

Any easy fix although it's a bit outdated at this point in time is to just `float` the container. (eg. `float: left;`) On another note, each `id` should be unique, meaning you can't use the same `id` twice in the same `HTML` document. You should use a `class` instead, where you can use that same `class` for multiple elements.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(255, 100, 0);
    margin: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Although this does work (thakyou) it causes other problems in the layout of my page that im probably at the moment too inexperienced to solve

Comment: By adding the `float` property you forces the element to act as a block element, so the `display: inline-block` doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution not involving Flex, because Flex doesn't work in older Browsers. 
Example:

```
.container {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:1024px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    background:#ececec;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:justify;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0pt;
    letter-spacing:-1em;
}

.cols {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:32%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-right:2%;
    border:0px;
    background:lightgreen;  
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:10pt;
    letter-spacing:normal;
}

.cols:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add a border: `2px solid #e60000`; to your 2nd div tag CSS.

Definitely it works

```
#Div2Id {
    border: 2px solid #e60000; --> color is your preference
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add

```
#container
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background:rgb(255,100,0);
    margin:0px;
    width:40%;
    height:100px;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

because whenever you write `display:inline-block` it takes an additional `margin-right:4px`. So, you need to remove it.