# Unable to center div on bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm unable to center a lot of div since I upgrade my bootstrap from 2.1 to 3.0

For example with this code:

```html
<div id="center" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">test</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <p>Am I centered ?</p>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Back</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I had this rule:

```
#center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But the result is:
[image]

Or another example, how to center this:

```html
<div id="center" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <li class="col-md-5">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><i class="icon-user"></i> aaaaaaaaa</li>
                <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i> bbbbbbbbbb</li>
                <li><i class="icon-envelopebug"></i> cccccccccccc</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-5">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><i class="icon-user"></i> aaaaaaaaa</li>
                <li><i class="icon-envelope"></i> bbbbbbbbbb</li>
                <li><i class="icon-envelopebug"></i> cccccccccccc</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to center a block level element using `margin: 0 auto;` it must also have a width that is smaller than its containing block (for the `auto` value to make sense) -  because `#container` is spanning the width of its parent (the `<body>`) there is simply no margin to distribute.

An alernative approach to `margin: 0 auto;` would be to set `.btn-toolbar` to `inline-block` and then centering it by adding `text-align: center;` to its containing block. You can apply the same concept to the second example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/94/

Comment: Thank you it works great for the button but I have a question with the list. How is it possible to have the same result but without the centered text :)   http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/99/

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, `margin:0 auto` doesn't work because the width of the element is `100%`. If you want it to work, you would have to set a width on the element:

```
.btn-toolbar {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

If you want to center the text and the button, you could add the class `text-center` to the parent element, in this case: `.row`. The styling of this class is simply `text-align: center`.

```
<div class="row text-center">
  ..
</div>
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3bUx/)

As @Adrift points out, it would be much more efficient to center the element by making it `inline-block`, as you can use `text-align:center` as opposed to `margin:0 auto` and avoid having to set a fixed width on the element. This will ensure that the element is centered regardless of its width. [(example here)](http://jsfiddle.net/b3bUx/1/) - don't forget you can just add the class `text-center` to the parent for centering.

It's also worth noting that `inline`/`inline-block` elements respect white-space in the markup, and thus generate space if present. If you want to remove this space, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859).

Comment: As you suggests, I followed the solution of @Adrift but thank you for the explanations ;)