# I can't center this input box despite trying text-align, overflow and clearfix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm throwing the kitchen sink at this one, but I'm not seeing how to center it.

I would guess that class="navbar-form navbar-left" has something to do with it but removing it or changing it to navbar-right does nothing.

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="problemcontainer">
<form class="myform" method="GET" action="servlet" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="dateFieldandCalendar">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input id="datepicker" name="pickedDate" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="datebtn">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Calculate Dates!</button> 
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Reset</button>
    <input id="month" name="monthHTML" value="" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="day" name="dayHTML" value="" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="year" name="yearHTML" value="" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="formID" name="formIDHTML" value="CaStateMSJID" type="hidden"/>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.problemcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: collapse;
}

.myform {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: collapse;
}

.input-group.date {
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: collapse;
}

.dateFieldandCalendar {
    overflow: collapse;

    text-align: center; 
}

.input-group-btn {
    text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
    text-align: center;
}

.input-group {
    text-align: center;
}

.datepicker {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H8LNA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are setting a width on the element, simply use `margin:0 auto` to center it.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2gK8k/)

```
.input-group.date {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

The reason `text-align:center` wasn't working, was because that property isn't respected by pure `block` level elements, in this case the `div`.

For an alternative approach, you could make the element `inline-block` and add `text-align:center` to the parent element. Bootstrap has a class for this, just add `text-center` to the element's class list.

Related: [Center div on Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040121/unable-to-center-div-on-bootstrap-3/19040195#19040195)

Comment: Thanks. How would I have centered it if I hadn't specified a width?