# how to remove white space between divs (CSS graph creating)

Tags: html, css

I have created a graph using CSS but i got some of troubles with inner divs (bar classes). There are white spaces between inner divs. I've tried by using float: left. it can remove white spaces, but inner divs are not adjacent to the bottom of outer div (graph class).

This is an example links (still not remove white space): http://dabblet.com/gist/2779082
Thank you

**HTML**

```
<div class="graph">
    <div style="height: 22px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 11px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 6px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 49px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 28px;" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.graph {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.bar {
    width: 8px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: yeah, its works. I wondering i must add html comments tags between close and open div tags.
</div><!-- --><div>

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
.bar {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.bar {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }
```

I am pretty sure that the white place will dissapear but because the border it is going to be another color. it takes 1px from each side of your `div`.

There always will be a margin between your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding: 0px;` to your `.graph`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin:0;` to you bar css, spaces between your graphs are removed..You can see it in the image...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the white spaces really between the divs, Try the following
instead of

```
<div class="graph">
    <div style="height: 22px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 11px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 6px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 49px;" class="bar"></div>
    <div style="height: 28px;" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

same exactly without spaces between divs

```
<div class="graph">
    <div style="height: 22px;" class="bar"/>
    <div style="height: 11px;" class="bar"/>
    <div style="height: 6px;" class="bar"/>
    <div style="height: 49px;" class="bar"/>
    <div style="height: 28px;" class="bar"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reply is a bit too late for this quesiton, but the answer might help someone else who has the same problem.

In fact I am not answering this question, the answer is in the link below.

[Why is there an unexplainable gap between these inline-block div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements)