# Centering a Row of Inline Images

Tags: css, image, inline

I have four icons I've set to display inline and I'm now trying to center the list they're contained in within a div.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="social_media">
     <ul>
           <li><a href="http://wwww.facebook.com"><img src="../images/social_media_icons/facebook_icon.png"></a></li>
           <li><a href="http://wwww.wikia.com"><img src="../images/social_media_icons/wikia_icon.png"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/social_media_icons/rss_icon.png"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/social_media_icons/mail_icon.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 #social_media
{
    width:220px;
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:0 2px;
}

#social_media ul li 
{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 3px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

The four icons are 48px square for a total of 192px wide, and each have horizontal margins of 3px for another 24px wide, adding to the whole list being 216px wide.  The div they're contained in (social_media) is 220px wide with 2px of horizontal padding for 216px of space in which the list, in theory, should fit perfectly.

However, when I actually do this, the fourth icon gets bumped down to the next row, directly under the first.  When I change 3px to auto, they all fit on the same row, but are too close together.  And regardless of what I do, the list is aligned to the left instead of the center where it's supposed to be.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the CSS you posted, you *may* have forgotten about the default `padding` on the `ul` element. In most browsers, it is `40px`. Resetting this value, however, **doesn't** solve the entire issue, as the real issue lies in the fact that `inline` elements respect the whitespace in the markup and generate `~2px` spaces when present. This is the root of the issue; i'd therefore suggest taking a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859), which addresses this issue specifically.

Given that there isn't any text involved, you could set `font-size:0` on the parent `ul` element, thus removing this space.  Assuming there actually is text, you would simply specify a new `font-size` on the child elements affected.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxm7Z/)

```
#social_media ul {
    padding:0;
    font-size:0;
}
```

Alternatively, the best approach would be to actually remove the whitespace from the markup. Take a look at the markup in [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LeLXs/).

Comment: Margin and padding were reset at the top of the page ;)

I tried removing the whitespace both through your method and commenting it out, and while both successfully reduced space between the icons to zero, I now can't get it to recognize the 3px margins (or 3px padding when I tried that).  It _does_, however, appear to be recognizing the 2px padding on the div.

Comment: Nope, just arranges them vertically again :\  I wonder, could it have something to do with the fact that I'm using .png images?  They have rounded (i.e. transparent) corners, but the sides take up the full 48x48.

Comment: @ZachCox Do you have an example where I can see this? A url or something? This doesn't really seem to be the case in the examples I posted; there is still a `3px` margin between the items.

Comment: Alright, i just added the "img" back in after ui li, and that seemed to get it to recognize the margins, though they're still arranged vertically in both inline and inline-block.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is currently being developed offline.  I can take a screenshot, though, give me one second.

Comment: @ZachCox To be honest, a screenshot probably wouldn't help; is there any chance you could made a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/) i'd be able to figure out the issue if you did that

Comment: @ZachCox The selector was wrong, you were making the `img` elements `inline-block`; it should have been the `li` items. [Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/ksg8D/)

Comment: Here, have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dense_Electric/4j6fA/

I've given the div a temporary green background for clarity.

Comment: AH, that was my problem!  I didn't realize I needed separate #social_media ul li and @social_medial ul li img sections.  I set it back to default inline and it worked *almost* perfectly fine.

It still isn't *quite* lining up in the perfect center, but I think I can fix that on my own (and if not, it's close enough that it doesn't really matter).

Comment: @ZachCox You would change the width of `#social_media` to `216px` as opposed to `220px`. [Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/L44h2/)

Comment: And adding text_align:center to #social_media ul li fixed that little problem.  My entire issue has been resolved, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
#social_media ul li img {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Well that certainly did _something_, but they're arranged vertically as if in a block.  Also, they now all have standard bullets again.

Comment: Increase #social_media width, must help to get them in a row.