# Centering dynamic div without using width

Tags: css

My question is simple, how can I center these [two elements](http://jsfiddle.net/MyVN4/) using the css "button" class dynamically? -> http://jsfiddle.net/MyVN4/ (I don't want to specify the width of the elements)

```
.button {
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   color: white;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px;
 }
```

I've been looking other similar questions but none of the solutions work for this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that they are `inline` elements, just set `text-align:center` on a **parent element**, in this case, the `body` element:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzBAn/)

```
#parent_element {
    text-align:center;
}
```

You usually only have to set a width on the element when it is a `block` level element and will be unaffected by `text-align:center`, (it would need `margin:0 auto`). Using `text-align:center` is probably the best method for centering, even if you have to change the display of an element to `inline-block`. Just be aware of the fact that `inline` elements [respect whitespace in the markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859).

Comment: Centering the entire `body` element is probably undesirable.

Comment: @Blazemonger This isn't centering the entire body element. The `body` element is `block` level, therefore this property will have no effect on it, especially since it has a width of `100%`.

Comment: Obviously I meant the entire *contents* of the `body` element.

Answer (score 4):

put `text-align: center;` on its parent (whatever its parent will be).

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for the edit. I haven't noticed this was a grammar site too. :)

Comment: Thanks! Makes more sense using its parent for this!!