# White Space between vertical nav bar and paragraph

Tags: css, html, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have some mysterious white space that I don't know how to get rid of. I have a vertical list and I want it to be right next to the paragraph with text. Here is my HTML and CSS

SOLVED BY jmgem I ALSO HAD TO READJUST THE SIZE OF MY PARAGRAPH ELEMENT SO IT WOULD FIT BESIDE THE NAV BAR

HTML

```
<div id="classOfferingList" class="classOfferingList" align="left">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" >General U.S. K-12 English Speaking Course</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" >University Preperation Course</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" >SAT Preperation Course</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" >GRE Preperation Course</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="classOfferingInfo" >
    <p>example text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.classOfferingList ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.classOfferingList ul li {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.classOfferingList ul li a {
  list-style:  none;
  margin: 1px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 35%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It's likely that the `inline-block` elements are causing this. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859)

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks for the answer but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Is this something you were looking for http://jsfiddle.net/32q6y/  *Changed your text color because I couldn't see it :p

Comment: @user3010773 Thats closer to what I was wanting. The problem is I want the text to sit with the nav bar. Like how in books they have the one large letter with the rest of the text around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I copied your code into jsfiddle. Go on in and have a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/GyuX5/

If I understand your question correctly, you wanted to put the paragraph right next to the vertical menu. So here's your adjusted CSS

```
.classOfferingList ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.classOfferingList ul li {
   margin: 5px 0px;
}

.classOfferingList ul li a {
  list-style:  none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

#classOfferingInfo {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I had your paragraph display as an inline-block, then I changed the width of the li a to 150px instead of 35%. Voila.

Chose not to use a left float as they tend to disrupt layouts as they become more complicated. try to imagine html/css as blocks filling up a row in the browser from left to right.

Comment: Hey thanks this pretty much fixed what I needed. I had to adjust the paragraph size as well (little bugger decided to go below my nav bar). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the two main div to the left then they will be right next to each other. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u64au/)

```
.classOfferingList {
    float: left;
}
.classOfferingList ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.classOfferingList ul li {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
#classOfferingInfo {
    float: left;
}
.classOfferingList ul li a {
  list-style:  none;
  margin: 1px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/TC856/

```
#classOfferingList > ul
{
    padding:0px;
}
```

you need to reset ul element

or your question could be this

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/TC856/1/)