# Unexplained gap between boxes in a form

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form at http://jsfiddle.net/np8ty/ and can't see any reason for the gap separating the red and beige boxes.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="checkout_form">
     <input type="text" size="20"   class="cc-number"  placeholder="Card number"/>
     <input type="text" class="cc-exp"  placeholder="MM/YY"  /> 
     <input type="text" class="cc-cvc"  placeholder="CVC"  />           
     <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just remove the whitespace in the markup. [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/xYnMA/) .. Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-left to your css like this:

```
#checkout_form input.cc-cvc{
    width: 109px;
    background-color: beige;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes removing the space will do the work. You may also use **float left** for both of the inputs.