# Display:inline not working?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to make the divisions of `class=unit-media` to display in single line  by having its parent `overflow-x:scroll` but not getting anywhere, Here is the code fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SH2EM/ any help would be highly appreciated, Thank you!

Here is code:
http://jsfiddle.net/SH2EM/1/

**CSS**

```
.media {
    width:auto;
    height:125px;
    background-color:#BBC;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding:15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.unit-media {
    display:inline;  /*Not working*/
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Comment: The classes in your CSS are wrong. Is that the problem?

Comment: Please post the code in the question

Comment: @JoshCrozier thank you for your response, the problem is with display:inline, its not displaying the classes as inline divisions, rather display as inline-block.

Comment: @TKA you didn't put quotes around class names in the fiddle.

Comment: @Popnoodles thank you for your response, the code is available in links mentioned.

Comment: @TKA Stackoverflow asks that you post code in the question, not just link to third-party sites, as that code may disappear causing this question to be useless. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Popnoodles Oops! sorry my mistake! I will be careful next time! any way Josh Crozier gave me the answer, so I will be resolving this question.

Comment: @TKA Do you mean removing the question? Questions remain on Stackoverlow for use by people having similar problems. Without that code this question may become useless to Stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work, the elements should not be floated - therefore remove `float:left`. Additionally, the `display` value should be `inline-block` as opposed to `inline`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dXAdt/)

```
.media-upload {
    height:125px;
    background-color:#BBC;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding:15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.unit-media {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

To address your other concern regarding the space between the elements - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859). Simply put, `inline` elements respect the whitespace in the markup. You can simply remove the whitespace in order to solve the problem.