# cant get rid of white space between text columns?

Tags: css

I am building a three column newspaper-like layout, but am stumped why there is spacing between my columns. I have tried removing padding, margin, border et.c  with no luck and I've been at this for en antire day.I need another set of eyes to help me.

```
center div {width: 150px; display: inline-block; background: lightgray; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}

center {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26n4e/2/

Comment: Remove the whitespace in the markup - [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LA8qm/) .. see [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements/19038859#19038859) for details.. By the way, the `center` tag is depreciated - don't use it!

Comment: `center{overflow:hidden} center div {float: left;}`

Comment: ***newspaper-like layout*** for this kind of layout, you should use ***column box layout*** instead which supports this very beautifully.

Comment: @user2930185 Here - http://jsfiddle.net/Ldvu3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/26n4e/4/

Remove space between `</div>` and `<div>`, closing div and opening div.

Also, don't use `center` tag