# css weird margin

Tags: html, css, margin

Does anyone know why in this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/seLFu)

the inner `<div>` displayed vertically instead of horizontally?

I use chrome element inspect can see a huge margin area on the right of each `<div>`, but without any margin value.

Found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-div-elements)

could be the answer to this question, too.  Just in case anyone needs it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DtCGF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens so because you are using `block` layout for each inner `div` (`display:block` as default for `div` elements). Instead you should use (for example ) `display:inline-block` and reduce `width` (to `33%` in my example) as it adds some extra pixels as spacing between three inner divs :

```
.cols_section > div{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/voIjq)

Another option is to use table layout, so you don't have to change `width` for each inner div:

```
.cols_section {
   display:table;
   width:100%;
}

.cols_section > div{
   display:table-cell;
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzhgb)

Comment: It should be noted that your example only works because it just so happens that two spaces have less width than `1%` of the parent - see my example posted as a question comment.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol : I've mentioned this, actually.

Comment: You have, but didn't give the reason why, just that it "adds some extra pixels" ;)

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol : By the way, I've just looked at your example – where I can read about this `>` feature? It a shame, but I have not heard about it.

Comment: HTML tags allow arbitrary whitespace between attributes... or at the end of them. In this case, by putting the whitespace inside the HTML tag instead of between tags, I've removed the empty space. Of course, in both cases, you should really be minifying your HTML so the whitespace wouldn't be there anyway XD

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol : I should have hit upon it by myself))) Well thank you very much for explanation! It is one of the reasons to answer questions here : one always discovers something new or something better)

Comment: Thanks, guys, @NiettheDarkAbsol your explaination is really clear, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Set width for each class to auto. That should solve your problem..

Example:

```
.cols_section {
    max-width: 1045px;
    height: 100px;
}

.col1 {
  background: green;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.col2 {
  background: yellow;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.col3 {
  background: blue;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```