# Why does this not render on 1 line

Tags: html, css

Why does this not render on 1 line?

I have to change div width to 24.5% for it work. I don't get it. 4 * 25% = 100%, right?

```
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 800px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
</style>

<nav>
    <div>Link</div>
    <div>Link</div>
    <div>Link</div>
    <div>Link</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't render in one line because `inline` elements [respect whitespace in the markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859).

If you remove the whitespace, it will [work as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/0rmmt8p8/). For brevity, see the link above for alternative methods.

Comment: @popovitsj Yea.. agreed.