# Spaces between <a> elements

Tags: html, css

Why are there space's between the pictures?
http://jsfiddle.net/dasmus/6Ltrs9tw/

CSS

```
.gallery{
width:900px;
height:640px;
}
a{
display:inline-block;
}

a img{
width:200px;
height:141px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a ><img src="http://1.1.1.1/bmi/alpatriott.ru/works/album/images/smile.jpg"></a>
    <a ><img src="http://1.1.1.1/bmi/alpatriott.ru/works/album/images/smile.jpg"></a>
    <a ><img src="http://1.1.1.1/bmi/alpatriott.ru/works/album/images/smile.jpg"></a>
    <a ><img src="http://1.1.1.1/bmi/alpatriott.ru/works/album/images/smile.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/a/19038859/1690081 this was the trick. (also float works) Why would it respect the whitespacejesus.

Answer (score 1):

because `display: inline-block` adds extra space between elements. There are hacks to take care of this but if you want the elements to touch you're better off just using `float:left`. Just be sure to either add `overflow:hidden` to a parent element or use a clearfix

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ltrs9tw/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't read that out in w3School.com

Comment: Don't read in w3school please :)

Comment: isn't w3school like the one who makes standards =).
What would you sugges to have for better reference?

Comment: @MihkelL. - No, w3schools is nothing like the one that makes the standards. That's the W3C, a completely different organisation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  a{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left; /* added */
  }
```

Comment: you don't need both, the point off using `inline-block` was to align the elements horizontally.