# Unexpected margin after inline-block element

Tags: html, css, margin

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/yxxhj33x/

As you can see, I have the `.links` element followed by a `input[type='text']` element. Unfortunately, there is a margin above the input, which won't go away when I add:

```css
.links {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.links a {
  background: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class='links'>
    <a href='#'>Blah</a>
    <a href='#'>Blah</a>
    <a href='#'>Blah</a>
    <a href='#'>Blah</a>
</div>
<input type='text'>
```

```
input[type='text'] {
  margin: 0;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [removing the space between inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859), you need to change the value of the `vertical-align` property on the `.links` element. It's worth pointing out that the default value is `baseline`. When it is set to `baseline` on an inline element, there is a [reserved space for letters such as f, j, p and q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278) (these letters hang lower (or are taller) than other letters, thus the reserved space).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkzbujcc/)

```
.links {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;   /* Added.. */
}
.links a {
    box-sizing: border-box;   /* Added.. */
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that the widths of the `a` elements didn't add up to `100%` (since the border isn't included in the element's width calculations). In order to remove the scollbar, add `box-sizing: border-box` to the anchor elements.

---

As a side note, since you're setting a width of `100%` on the parent `.links` element, it really doesn't need to have a `display` of `inline-block`. You should make it a `block` level element (by omitting `display: inline-block`, since it's already a `div` and `block` level by default). In doing so, you actually don't need to add `vertical-align: bottom` anymore, since `block` level elements don't respect this property.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1oz8mce/)

```
.links {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.links a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```