# Why are my list-items not displayed inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a image slider based on a `<ul>`.
The problem is that the `<li>` are not displayed `inline-block`.

I already tried this:

```
.slider ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But that doesn't work. I also tried `display:inline-flex;` but no result.
An other thing I tried is to replace the `<li>` by a `<div>` but that to without any result.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ph3kvb1/1/)

I normally works so I don't know why it doesn't work this time.

So can somebody help me fixing this problem?

Comment: Why not setting display: inline-block for li ?

Comment: Floating converts *any* inline-level box into its block-level equivalent. This means not only does inline (and inline-block) become block, but also inline-flex becomes flex.

Comment: for start, a floating an element automatically makes it into a box, so go with float or with inline, not both !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent element; in this case, the `ul`.

In addition, the `white-space` property won't have an effect on the floated elements, therefore you need to remove `float: left`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdg1fqg8/)

```
.slider ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slider ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That works but now I have a small white space between the images? I used the `float:left` for that so How can I fix that?

Comment: @Vinc199789 For the space between the elements, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859). Here is an updated example http://jsfiddle.net/wdg1fqg8/