# CSS to add commas between <dd>s

Tags: css, pseudo-element

## Best attempt so far

```css
dd { display: inline; margin: 0; }
dd + dd::before {
  content: ', ';
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>One</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>

  <dt>Two</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>
</dl>
```

I'd like to add commas between the `<dd>` elements using CSS pseudo-elements. The only problem with the above attempt is that there's a space before each comma.

When I do this with `<li>`s, I can use `::after` pseudo-elements and target `li:last-of-type` to remove the comma from the last item, but I can't figure out a way to target the last `<dd>` in my example. I think the proposed `has` selector could help (like `dd:has(+ dd)`). Is there any workaround in CSS3?

Or is there a good way to get rid of the space? If I have to, I'll use a negative margin to pull the comma back toward the preceding word.

Comment: To fix the whitespace: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space that you are seeing between the elements is determined by the parent element's `font-size`. Inline elements respect the whitespace in the markup.

[One way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859) to remove this would be to set the parent element's `font-size` to `0`, and then reset the children element's `font-size`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859) for alternative approaches.

```css
dl {
  font-size: 0;
}
dd, dt {
  font-size: 16px;
}
dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
dd + dd::before {
  content: ', ';
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>One</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>

  <dt>Two</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: You could also remove the space between the HTML elements like this: `<dd></dd><dt></dt><dd></dd>`. It's because of the element have a (default) `display` value of `inline` or `inline-block` that it adds these spaces.

Comment: @mnsth Yep--that's why I linked to this other answer of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a negative left margin to the pseudo-element in `em`s.  `-0.2em` seems to work well:

```css
dd, dt {
  font: 16px verdana;
}

dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

dd+dd::before {
  content: ', ';
  margin-left: -0.2em;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>One</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>

  <dt>Two</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the `', '` before an element seems wrong to me. Imho it should be after the element, but of course not on the last element.

Next to that, first the space is removed and added later again which seems a bit strange to me.

How about leaving the space as is and simply add a comma after the element using `::after`.

The problem you run into is is that the last element still contains a comma, but you have not trouble with a `,` floating somewhere and as a bonus, it is at the place it should be.

So basically you don't want the last element to match. Luckily we have something we can use for this.
By using [`:not(:last-child)`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_not) you target all elements except the selector used inside the parentheses.

```css
dd, dt {
  font: 16px verdana;
}

dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

dd:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: ',';  
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div class="group">
    <dt>One</dt>
    <dd>one</dd>
    <dd>two</dd>
    <dd>three</dd>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <dt>Two</dt>
    <dd>one</dd>
    <dd>two</dd>
    <dd>three</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: :last-child doesn't work here. Notice the comma after the first "three". Need some kind of sibling selector to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Strange that I missed that. The easiest solution would be to to group them. I've changed my code to reflect that.