# sum of elements' width is 100% but the last element goes to next line

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<img>` elements in a div like this:

```
<div>
   <img style="width: 10%;">
   <img style="width: 80%;">
   <img style="width: 10%;">
</div>
```

but the last image goes to next line. the `box-sizing` property of the div is `border-box`.

what is the problem?

Comment: It's because inline elements (like `img` elements) respect the whtiespace in the markup... see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859).

Answer (score 3):

Images and other inline elements are affected by whitespace in the html. This example shows your html with whitespace removed. http://jsbin.com/qoxedepifi/1/edit?html,css,output. You could set the `display: inline-block; float:left` which will ignore white-space. Or you could set the property `white-space-collapse: discard;` on the parent element.

Comment: Actually.. `white-space-collapse: discard` currently isn't supported by any browsers. It doesn't seem like it will be any time soon eiither.. http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#white-space-collapsing

Answer (score 0):

```
img{float:left;}
```

Your can add float left on the images.