# css calc() not producing expected result

Tags: html, css, calc

I am trying to achieve a specific look of responsive search bar where I display search input, select option for filters and submit button in one row. Submit button and select have defined widths of 44px and 110px respectively and I want search input field to occupy rest of available space, therefore I use `width: calc(100% - 154px);`. But it is not working as intended. Please see example here https://jsfiddle.net/t97fqqxu/

HTML:

```
<div id="main-search">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." />
        <select>
            <option>Option</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-search {
    background-color: @palette-white;
}
#main-search form {
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}

#main-search input[type="text"] {
    width: calc(100% - 154px);
}

#main-search select {
    width: 110px;
}

#main-search input[type="submit"] {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm taking advantage of bootstrap 3's box-model, thus no mater margins and paddings, widths will always be 44px and 110px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't account for the `border` on the `input` elements. By default, the `border`/`padding` is added to the element's width/height. In other words, even if you give an element a width of `110px`, you still need to account for the element `padding`/`border`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/khLbu2Lm/)

You could either remove the border, or use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to account for the `border` in the element's width/height calculation:

```
input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
}
```

or..

```
input[type="text"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In addition, it's worth pointing out that `inline` elements [respect the whitespace in the markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859), you also needed to remove that too. See the updated example above.

Comment: I just updated my answer to signify that I am using border-box, but will look into your answer, as you got it working.

Comment: @Ilja Then whitespace is the issue. See the last portion of my answer.

Comment: I applied what you said in my fiddle it works fine, yet in production, that uses same code, whenever I take say -10px away, it seems to grab larger chunk off is calc calculating 100% from parent or element itself?

Comment: @Ilja It would be 100% of the parent element. Not sure why that's occurring for you if it works in the fiddle though.

Comment: I inspected the element it seems that whenever I do -10px it calculates to 90% width and if I do -20px it calculates to 80%, so it does not respect px or something?

Comment: never mind, I was using less and it compiles it weirdly for some reason

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. If you're using LESS you need to escape it, otherwise the addition/subtraction will be evaluated. Surround it with `~".."`.. for instance, `~"calc(100% - 110px)"`

Comment: Oh wow, never encountered this before, it does fix the issue. Thank you!