# How to create a foreach that doesn include whites space between the looped elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

I have a `foreach` which outputs div elements, like this:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: names -->
  <div class="grid__item">
      <p data-bind="text: $index"></p>
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

```javascript
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.names = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Woop' },
        { name: 'Dee' },
        { name: 'Doo' }
    ]);

}

app = new AppViewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

This results in the DOM in:

```html
<div class="grid__item">
  <p>0</p>
</div>
<div class="grid__item">
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="grid__item">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

However, I need to have **no white spaces** between the `div` elements, i.e. I want it to render like this:

```html
<div class="grid__item">
  <p>0</p>
</div><div class="grid__item">
  <p>1</p>
</div><div class="grid__item">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Honest question, just to check: this is not by any chance an instance of the XY-problem, where X is in fact ["getting gaps between divs"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19038799/419956)?

Comment: yes same problem just needed the knockout syntax

Answer (score 2):

Should be simple enough, just remove the whitespace in your comment block:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.names = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Woop' },
        { name: 'Dee' },
        { name: 'Doo' }
    ]);
}

app = new AppViewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: names --><div class="grid__item">
  <p data-bind="text: $index"></p>
</div><!-- /ko -->
```

However, this feels awkward. So I'll repeat my comment here: Honest question, just to check, this is not by any chance an instance of the XY-problem, where X is in fact ["getting gaps between divs"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19038799/419956)?