# Jquery append() on another line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I thought this would be simple but this code outputs my spans on the same line.

```
$("<p/>")
    .append($("<span/>", {
        class:"time",
        text: content.time }))
    .append($("<span/>", {
        class: "content",
        text: content.message
    }));
```

But since it append these elements without a newline, my spans end up needing manual spacing, which just isn't possible at my current scale.

```
<p><span class="time">now</span><span class="content">Lorem Ipsum ...</span></p>
```

How can I force jQuery to manually append my spans on a new line? I've tried using `.after` to.

EDIT:

I guess I was a bit unclear, so far `.append("\n")` is what I'm looking for, if there are any better ways, I'm all ears but appending a `<br/>` tag is definitely not what I was looking for.

```
<p>
   <span class="time">now</span>
   <span class="content">Lorem Ipsum ...</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Append a <br/> too. Why do you expect append to insert any whitespace or BRs by itself?

Comment: I don't and I guess I was unclear on that. Some elements need the line break in html to display correctly... I don't want the spans rendered on new lines but rather the html to have both spans on separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the HTML element to be appeneded to a newline, you can insert a newline character, `\n`, using the `.after()` method before appending the second `span`. In doing so, there will be a space between the words (since `inline` span elements [respect the whitespace in the markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859)).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/csk54md2/)

```
$("p").append($("<span/>", {
    class: "time",
    text: content.time
}).after('\n')).append($("<span/>", {
    class: "content",
    text: content.message
}));
```

Comment: And the choice of after over another append?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$("<p/>")
    .append($("<span/>", {
        class:"time",
        text: content.time }))
    .append("<br/>")
    .append($("<span/>", {
        class: "content",
        text: content.message
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Append line break separately, not by joining it to text, then it works:

```
$("<p/>")
    .append($("<span/>", {
        class:"time",
        text: content.time }))
    .append($("<br />"))
    .append($("<span/>", {
        class: "content",
        text: content.message
    }))
    .append($("<br />"));
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnh9t70s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` is inline element. You can change it to block with CSS:

```
span {
    display: block;
}
```

or use `after` pseudoelement:

```
span::after { 
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

or use `<br />`

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend overriding the default display of span.