# In css how to joining two div classes without space?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my css I have the following:--

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: arial, georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}


.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}


.header1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 90px;
  clear:both;
  background: url(../images/tooplate_footer1.png) no-repeat; 
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(250px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(250px);
  -o-transform: translateX(250px);
  transform: translateX(250px);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}






input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .header1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(250px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(250px);
  -o-transform: translateX(250px);
  transform: translateX(250px);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .header1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}






@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }


  .header1 {
    max-width: 1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   clear:both;
  }
```

and my html is following;-

```
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="header1"></div> 
   </body>
```

Now I am getting the page like
[image: this page]

I want to remove this space.So,that two div class can join together. I have used margin-top:0px; but space is not removing..suggest me please.

Comment: `margin-top: negative value px;`? For example `margin-top: -5px;`.

Comment: Check [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/q2vcvjuc/2/) fiddle. I only changed the header1 image

Comment: And what is the purpose of `jquery` tag???

Comment: Comment out the white spaces between those two `div` like so: `</div><!--     --><div class="header1">`.

Comment: @ Rvervuurt,thank you boss..Its working..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Wow, really?  It takes *all* of this code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between your two divs comes from the div that wraps around the back, it makes the div higher than it looks.

To move it up, use a negative value for the margin-top.

For example

```
.header1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 90px;
  clear:both;
  background: url(../images/tooplate_footer1.png) no-repeat; 
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  margin-top: -4px; //HERE
}
```

Comment: Use of negative margin is discouraged if there are other optimal solutions because it perform differently in different browsers.

Comment: @Enigma Says who? I've never heard that before.

Comment: It is ok to have negative margins to achieve certain visual effects, but having negative margin means there is something incorrectly styled in your layout. Google It you will find tons of reasons for it ;)

Comment: Unless you come with a source, I don't believe it @Enigma. All sources I find say it's perfectly fine, highly compatible with old browsers, and are valid CSS according to W3C since CSS2.

Comment: I am not saying it is invalid  :), I am just saying we should be cautious with them and if there are other solutions then we should go for it.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements]