# Unexpected space between two divs

Tags: css, css-position

This is my code-

```
.a{
background:blue;
padding:30px;
Position:relative;
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
}
```

If 2 divs both with class `a` are entered, then there is a small space between it

Comment: It's because [`inline-block` elements respect the white-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859) in the markup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use 'float:left' and remove 'display:inline-block' hope it will solve problem