# How to remove line in the middle?

Tags: html, css

How to remove line in middle of two div's?

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='lolol'></div>
        <div id='lol'></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
#lolol {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: green;
    }
#lol {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: blue;
    }
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/daniladyabin/fy3yhx4f/

Comment: See: [Why is there an unexplainable gap between these inline-block div elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859)

Comment: I vote to close, this has been answered by @JoshCrozier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens when one uses inline-block `<div>`s, and most of the time it's due to the fact that the code formatting somehow created a space character between the blocks. You just try to erase anything in the HTML that's between your two blocks.

edited Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3w0ewc5/

Comment: `<div id='lolol'></div><div id='lol'></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set `font-size: 0;` of the parent `<div id='container'>`

For example:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy3yhx4f/3/

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the  solution online and apparently closing part of your tag on the next line will fix this

```
 <div>text</div
><div>text</div
><div>text</div
><div>text</div
><div>text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle I did: https://jsfiddle.net/benF/fy3yhx4f/5/

What I did is on you `#lol` element I did `float:left`

and the gap went away so check it out at the link I gave You