# Remove spacing between <p> without using a margin?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the space between the `<p>` inside this code:

CSS:

```
.ban {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 248px;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML:
(I don't think I can use a div to be outside of a `p`)

```
<div class="ban">
  <p>
     text
  </p>
  <p>
     text
  </p>
  <p id="text">
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

[image: image of the space to be removed]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859

Comment: or add `float:left` to `p` and then `clear` the `floats` with `clear:both`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: inline-block` have that inconvenience. If you put a return character between the elements that small space appears. To avoid that you need to put all elements together:

```
<div class="ban">
    <p>text</p><p>text</p><p id="text">text</p>
</div>
```

Look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/zoavukL6/).

Try to separate the paragraphs and you'll see the result.

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the `<p>`s are constant, meaning you change them, and they're not dynamic, then simply add a fake div to cover up the space like follows:

```css
.ban {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 248px;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
  div.fake {
    height: 72px;
    width: 10px;
    background: beige;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 253px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="fake"></div>

<div class="ban">
  <p>
     text<br>more<br>frikin<br>text<br>to<br>take<br>up<br>space
  </p>
  <p>
     text<br>some<br>other<br>text
  </p>
  <p id="text">
    text<br>hi<br>how<br>are<br>you
  </p>
</div>
```