# CSS BUG: extra space between vertical divs

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please help me understand where the extra space between divs is coming from and how to get rid of it?

Here is the page:
http://www.infinitygap.com/temp/bug.html

Thanks!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* The problem we're trying to avoid is link rot: what happens when that bug page goes away and no one can see what the original problem was?

Comment: try `vertical-align: top;` or `vertical-align: bottom;`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements

Comment: This is actually not about a space between two side-by-side elements (David's comment above). Similarly, however, this is the result of browser defaults and could be resolved by using reset.css. Additionally, there's a lot of other problematic code in the example, which I've duplicated and commented on here: http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/YqNLNp?editors=0100

Comment: just add `margin-top: 0px` to the `<p>` inside of `.sub-footnote`, it will fix your issue and then delete this question, it will no longer be valid since there is no code posted.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - You can't delete a question with an up-voted answer.

Comment: I voted to close either way, patato potato

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the margin on the paragraph element that is in the `.sub-footnote`. If you remove it, you will be fine.

To understand this bug you should understand 2 concepts:

1. Margin collapsing between descendant elements. The margin on your pragraph is reflected on the `.sub-footnote` element. [Read an article on sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/).
2. Transformation doesn't actually change the DOM flow. So even it the margin looks like in the middle of the `.sub-footnote` element, it is not.