# Calculate the width in pixel of white space given certain font-size and font-family

Tags: css, fonts

Is it possible to calculate the width in pixel of white space given certain font-size and font-family?

For example, if I plan to [use negative margin-left to offset the white space between inline-blocks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), I need to know the width of white space.

```
ul > li{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-left:-???px;/*calculate this one*/
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the margin-left technique there a better methods but [**in general**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19038875/2802040) it's `.25em` which at 16px is 4px. I'd use `em' for preference then you don't have to change it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: @Paulie_D `This usually equates to .25em (or 4px)` Where did you get this one? Any reference?

Comment: Nope...it just is...is the size of a "space" apparently. However, the *negative margin* solution is considered to be the [**worst**](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) solution of them all...expecially nowadays.