# How to remove gaps between divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have gaps between divs, [image] it happens because I have following css rules

```
*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

actually the reason is **box-sizing** property, the question is how to disable this rule only for parent div and cos I need this rule for all other elements?

He is my screen with all ruls [image]

With this configuration [image]it works, but after this I have a problem with all other elements

[image: screen3]

Here is code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4j27tsdL/

Comment: How you do this would depend on the HTML which you haven't included in the question

Comment: As Rory points you can create a new selector to override that rule based on your HTML structure ... but Aside are you sure the gaps are generated by that property ? I don't see how the box-sizing could create those gaps

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"?

Comment: actually this rule from Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com) file, and looks like ` *,:after,:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box} `

Comment: I don't think it is that property that is causing those gaps. Could you post all of your relevant code.

Comment: I'm guessing the gaps are coming from the line breaks in the HTML where you probably have every `div` on it's own line. You can either connect them via comments, or `font-size:0` their parent container and they go away, but I have yet to find a better solution.

Comment: I was looking at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements), but it does not help me

Comment: I think 'absoluted position' is not a reason, cos when I uncheck box-sizing it woks as I expect, please look at screen3

Comment: You are right @nightmare I have checked again and any of the already posted answers will work for you using the classname `OrderRege145...`

Comment: Guys I added https://jsfiddle.net/4j27tsdL/ so you can check it

Comment: Check this with the selector `#test > div` https://jsfiddle.net/4j27tsdL/5/

Comment: It works in your example, thanks a lot!! I'll check it in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing good. Just need to change the value of property. Try this once. It is fully tested.

```
*, :after, :before {
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the children:

```
.childElements{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

But, for your question, only to remove the border-box from parent and not the children elements then you need to use css for both again even you applied on *: Also, note the following wouldn't work as you're expecting the gap. The above css rule work.

```
.parents{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.childElements{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

:) The confusing answer for confusing question for someone...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
.parents-parent > .parent {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

when you know the parent because `* > .parent` would be too much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your element is called `.myClass`, add this to your CSS.

```
.myClass, .myClass:before, .myClass:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

More info on [box sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).