# Divide 3 divs in 3 columns without using float and flex

Tags: html, css

I tried by using `display inline-block` to achieve 3 columns but 3rd column comes at separate row:

```css
.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
}
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 33.33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div>
  <div class="column">def</div>
  <div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: a veary simple way you can solve it, Just removed `min-width: 300px` and `margin-right: -5px;`

[Jsfiddel_link](https://jsfiddle.net/gxvLk5gp/2/)

Comment: you want to work it for bigger screen just use Mediaquery with `margin-right`

Comment: What about using Grid? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default `inline-block` count space as a element. You can do this in two different ways:

> 1. Method (Using Font Size)

```css
*,*:after,*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size:0px;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*min-width: 300px;*/
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div>
  <div class="column">def</div>
  <div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

> 2. Method Removing extra Space

```css
*,*:after,*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*min-width: 300px;*/
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div><!--
  --><div class="column">def</div><!--
  --><div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

> As per your comment you want `margin-right:5px` and achieve same thing. for this you can use width in `calc` format. check below snippet

```css
*,*:after,*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 5px);
  width: -moz-calc(33.33% - 5px);
  width: -webkit-calc(33.33% - 5px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*min-width: 300px;*/
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div><!--
  --><div class="column">def</div><!--
  --><div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have to give some margin-right of 5px to each column class and still want to achieve in a single row. I mean divide rest of the space in 33.33% for each column.

Comment: @TusharKhanna check updated answer for `margin-right:5px` solution.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know this is exactly what you need , i have remove the default whitespace of the `inline-block` using `font-size:0` and add `box-size property` you dont need to change the width `33.3% to 33%` the width please check the snippet

```css
 .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div>
  <div class="column">def</div>
  <div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have to give some margin-right of 5px to each column class and still want to achieve in a single row. I mean divide rest of the space in 33.33% for each column.

Comment: if you need to set `margin-right` to this div then you need to decrease the div width , other wise you need to set padding to `.coloum` class and add a new div inside the `.coloum` class

Comment: @JishnuVS , you change `font-size:0`? why?

Comment: `display:inline-block` have default white-space., We need to remove the space that's why, we have other options remove white space

Answer (score 1):

**Use Table for it, Best Option**

No width, No Float

```css
table{table-layout:fixed;width:500px;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default browser renders a gap between two div which are positioned inline.

Making the parent `width:100%,` and children `width:33.33%` will not make children fit in the parent, because DOM calculates the gap between child div.

To make the child div fit the parent, you need to modify the width smaller than 33.33%.

If you still want to use 33.33% width. Try this

[Link For reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/ezkjx36p/2/)

[Unexpected gap between div inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to solve this issue is to set the `.wrapper` to `display: table;` and set its children to `display: table-cell;`. See the example below for the outcome.

```css
.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   display: table;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 33.33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div>
  <div class="column">def</div>
  <div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are working in bigger screen like (1600,1920) then please use media query. And nothing to do any changes in margin and other as well.**

Please update this property

For < 1366 screen resolution use this css

```
width:32.90% //instead of 32.90% you may use width: 32%;
```

**For > 1366 width:33% is working**

in **.column** class

```
width: 33%;
```

So column class look like

```
.column {
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 150px;
        width: 33%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        min-width: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }
```

Because it's 1px border surrounded to div.**And their is default Margin:8 to body tag.**
[image]

**Width:33% is not working in 1366 screen resolution. So here you must need to use width:32.90% either 32%**
[image]

Comment: If i make it 32% then it comes in a single row but still it doesnt span whole width. By 33% it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please check answer i have attached and image with made changes in width:33% nothing else.

Comment: It's because of you are doing testing in 1366 screen resolution so here you need to add 32%  for width.

Answer (score 0):

Do change in Width and add Box-Sizing will help you.

```
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 33.1%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the div in one line **in your editor**.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">abc</div><!--
  --><div class="column">def</div><!--
  --><div class="column">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex`, flex is very good to make responsive div. It's a simple example.

--- HTML ----

```
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <your-element class="item"> 1 </your-element>
  <your-element class="item"> 2 </your-element>
  <your-element class="item"> 3 </your-element>
</div>
```

--- CSS ---

```
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  // if you want to lots of items, will be wrapped
}
.item {
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

and if your items have `margin`, you can calculate that like this.

```
.item {
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(33.3% - 10px);
}
```

Example : [image]

I hope will be helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following properties to your `column` class

```
.column {
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 150px;
        width:32%;
        float:left;
        margin-left:4px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        min-width: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }
```

**Reason**

- `float:left;` property will align your div's on left hand side
- `width:32%;` property will give width of 32 % instead of 33.33% as
  1px you are assigning to border, which needs to be accommodated from 
  the width itself.
- `margin-left:4px;` property will add spacing    between divs, this is
  for nicety.

Answer (score -3):

Your column class needs a couple of minor fixes, float and width changes:

```
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

Comment: It's possible you just need to update this property  width: 33%; no need to add float:left.