# how to make two input tags inline with 50% space consumed by each?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a form in which I have a total width of my form of 800 px. Now I want in my form the firstname and lastname to be at the very top but in the same line.
My HTML code is as follow:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="first">
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="first">
```

and my CSS code is as follow:

```
.first{
    border:1px solid #E5E5E4;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

but of these text inputs are coming in different lines. I searched a lot of questions but I am not getting the exact answer to my problem as of attaining them in a single line. None of the solutions described earlier has been able to solve the problem.
please tell the solution to form them in one single line.

Comment: add float:left to your class :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements

Comment: and you have to consider padding and border also, so box-sizing:border-box + removing white spaces

Comment: I don't even know why this question has been downvoted. Looks like we have an angry silent downvoter around

Comment: @JeremyThille because it's a N-th duplicates of question already well answered :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif    I am really sorry to say but none of the answers provided there; even in the link you just mentioned has solved my problem yet.

Comment: @JeremyThille here we provided only one, but i can list for you at least 5 question dealing about 50%/50%, issue with whitespace, issue with box-sizing, etc ... so as small search and he get his answer

Comment: and did you read my comment :) i provided the answer too

Comment: The problem now is, almost every question has been asked already, and there's always a dupe somewhere. So how can we get some rep?

Answer (score 2):

**[Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** is awesome at this kind of things. Compatible back to IE10.

```css
.inputs {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex-basis : 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="first">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="first">
</div>
```

Comment: Yay, instant silent downvote for a perfectly working snippet! Happy new year to you too

Comment: (not me) i agree flex is good but i think it's better to explain him first his issue :) then provide better alternative ;) so he will understand that with flex we won't have to worry about white space and box-sizing, etc