# How to disable Html auto formatting in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tinymce

I have code below in my Wordpress TinyMce editor:

```html
<section style="box-sizing: border-box;"><section style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; background: red; height: 30px;"></section><section style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; background: blue; height: 30px;"></section></section>
```

Then I have this as outcome:
[Two element block in a same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHljw.png)

However, when wordpress render this html, it will beautify the Html and turn my raw html to the following:

```html
<section style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<section style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; background: red; height: 30px;"></section>
<section style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; background: blue; height: 30px;"></section>
</section>
```

[Two elements not in the same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGWnU.png)

After hours research. I notice that is because the space between two inline-block. **I have tried the "font-size: 0" method and it work perfectly in this simple case.**

However, sometimes I need to copy a complicated raw html to my Wordpress site. Adding a "font-size:0" attribute will mess up the entire thing. Thus, **I am looking for a solution without touch the html** and wondering if any one can tell me how to disable this auto formatting in Wordpress or just disable the "auto new line" at the end of each elements.

Thanks very much :-]

Comment: please take the time to read ALL the answers to know all the way to deal with that space

Comment: Hi Temani, the problem for me is I need to copy many complicated raw html. And they are actually working! And it mess up only because WP add a new line at the end of my element. Currently those solution require me to modify HTML a lot. Therefore, I need a solution without touching the HTML.

Comment: that's why I told you to read all the answers : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33257267/8620333 as you don't need to touch the html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039075/8620333

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038859/8620333

Comment: Hi Temani, these solution doesn't help. Because Wordpress will add a newline at the end of each elements when it render to post.

Comment: I now reading the source code in formatting.php, but just can't find where it put the "\n" to each elements.

Comment: One solution is install Plugin "Raw HTML". Since it's marked Duplicated. I can't answer myself. Hopefully this can help others.