# Firefox is adding horizontal spacing between <td> tags

Tags: html, css

Ok, so this might be a stupid question, but I'm trying to make a 3-column table, but Firefox is adding a 1-2 pixel space between all the  columns. The table looks fine in Chrome. How can I eliminate this extra spacing? I'm not able to see these spaces when I inspect it with dev tools.

```html
<table role="presentation" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" style="background:#F1F1F1; max-width:640px; border-spacing:-1; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; min-width:120px; width:33.33%;">
      <img id="IMG-small" src="https://picsum.photos/640/300?random=1" alt="" width="213" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:480px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
    </td>
    <td style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; min-width:120px; width:33.33%;">
      <img id="IMG-small" src="https://picsum.photos/640/300?random=2" alt="" width="213" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:480px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
    </td>
    <td style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; min-width:120px; width:33.33%;">
      <img id="IMG-small" src="https://picsum.photos/640/300?random=3" alt="" width="213" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:480px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm developing this for some email marketing, so I'm not able to use any kind of JavaScript and any advanced CSS is basically a no-go, since I need to account for a broad range of email clients. This is also why I'm not using DIVs to do the layout.

The result that I'm looking for is to have all the  columns appear on a single line within the  instead of wrapping to multiple lines.

Comment: Here is a CodePen example:

[link](https://codepen.io/jedizombeh/pen/xNQGwj?editors=1000)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Click the `<>` to load the editor.

Comment: Why are you setting the display on the table cells to `inline-block`? Don't do that. Better yet, don't use tables for layout.

Comment: Like I said in my question, This is for EMAIL marketing. Tables are used for layout in HTML emails.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is `whitespace` due to you setting `td { display: inline-block; }`. If you really need that, a way to solve it is to set the parent element's `font-size: 0;`:

```html
<table role="presentation" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" style="background:#F1F1F1; max-width:640px; border-spacing:-1; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;">
  <tr style="font-size: 0;">
    <td style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; min-width:120px; width:33.33%;">
      <img id="IMG-small" src="https://picsum.photos/640/300?random=1" alt="" width="213" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:480px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
    </td>
    <td style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; min-width:120px; width:33.33%;">
      <img id="IMG-small" src="https://picsum.photos/640/300?random=2" alt="" width="213" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:480px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
    </td>
    <td style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; min-width:120px; width:33.33%;">
      <img id="IMG-small" src="https://picsum.photos/640/300?random=3" alt="" width="213" style="display:block;width:100%;height:auto;max-width:480px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Remember to set the font-size you actually need for any text you might have inside the table on the `td` elements.

Comment: Ah! YOU are awesome, THANK YOU!!! It never occurred to me that it would be whitespace from the inline-block declaration. I do need to keep that, so that the email can re-flow and wrap on mobile devices. 

Again, you're a lifesaver. I was literally beating my head against my desk over this one. LOL